# Rails JSON parsing help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am getting a json response from a site that should be giving me opening hours from Monday to Sunday

The json response looks like this

```
"listing_opening_hours"=>["a:7:{i:0;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:6:\"MONDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}i:1;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:7:\"TUESDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:8:\"09:30 AM\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:8:\"08:25 PM\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}i:2;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:9:\"WEDNESDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}i:3;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:8:\"THURSDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}i:4;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:6:\"FRIDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}i:5;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:8:\"SATURDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}i:6;a:4:{s:11:\"listing_day\";s:6:\"SUNDAY\";s:17:\"listing_time_from\";s:0:\"\";s:15:\"listing_time_to\";s:0:\"\";s:14:\"listing_custom\";s:0:\"\";}}"]
```

How do I get the opening and closing hours for each day of the week?

How would I go about formatting a json string to send back to update the hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `listing_opening_hours` has been serialized using PHP serialization - you'll need to deserialize it before you can read it normally.

PHP_serialize is a gem that will allow you to deseralize the value - https://rubygems.org/gems/php_serialize

Comment: That's great, thank you. Would it be normal for the site to be expecting the data to be re-serialized to send back?

Comment: That I don't know. Hopefully the API has some kind of documentation that will explain the data format it expects.